# Permissions for Preconfigured Pages?

Tags: community-builder

I used the ["Export Page" feature in Experience Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_export_page.htm&type=5) to create a "Proconfigured Page"; it now appears when I choose **Add Page > Standard**:
[image: Screenshot of New Page dialog]

However, we have a team who are not System Admins who will need to create such pages, and when I login as user with that profile, I do not see the exported page.  The profile has the "Create and Set Up Experiences" system permission to allow access to the builder.

How is access to exported "preconfigured pages" managed?  I can find nothing in setup.

Answer (score 0):

I tried giving the non-admin profile the same permissions noted on the linked documentation needed to create a "template, theme, or page", which are "Customize Application", "Create and Set Up Experiences", and "View Setup and Configuration."  The profile already had the last two, so I only needed to add "Customize Application."  This has fixed the issue, although I'd prefer not to give that permission to these users, it will have to do for now, unless someone can suggest a better solution.